# Какое значение должна вернуть pinvoke функция типа IntPtr, в случаях, когда в описании WinAPI возвращаемым значением указан NULL?

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

есть WinAPI функция [SetParent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633541(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
HWND WINAPI SetParent(
  _In_     HWND hWndChild,
  _In_opt_ HWND hWndNewParent
);
```

> Возвращаемое значение
>
> Type: HWND
>   Если функция выполнена успешно, возвращаемое значение -- handle к предыдущему родительскому окну.
>   Если функция не выполнилась, возвращаемое значение -- NULL. Для получения дополнительной информации, вызовите GetLastError.

Я использую [pinvoke-обёртку](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setparent) с соответствующего сайта.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
```

Как мне проверить, что функция вернула `NULL` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `IntPtr.Zero`:

> When calling the Windows API from managed code, you can pass
>   `IntPtr.Zero` instead of `null` if an argument is expected to be either
>   a pointer or a `null`.
>   ...
>   You can also test for a null return value from Windows API function calls that return either a pointer or a `null` by comparing the returned value with `IntPtr.Zero`. For example, the call to the `GetWindow` function in the following example tries to retrieve the handle of a non-existent window. If it were called from unmanaged code, the function would return `null`, but when it is called from managed code, it returns `IntPtr.Zero`.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.intptr.zero(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
   public static void Main()
   {
      IntPtr hwnd = new IntPtr(3);
      IntPtr hOwner = GetWindow(hwnd, GW_OWNER);
      if (hOwner == IntPtr.Zero)
         Console.WriteLine("Window not found.");
   }
```